# iOS Settings Bundle strangely disappeared

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist, settings.bundle

I'm working on some iOS app that involves connecting to a server and has an in-build Settings.Bundle which stored the hostname to that server.
This app has been prepared by someone else and is over a year old by now. The settings bundle and connection always worked perfectly fine, regardless of how they work. It worked this afternoon still when tested. Yet after lunch I came back and nothing worked anymore and I'm clueless on what the problem might be.

Before lunch I had some issues with an app with the same bundle identifier so I had this app's Bundle Identifier changed in the info.plist that I have been using to keep those matters in check.

Also I had been trying to create an .ipa-file for testing purposes. So I was busy with archiving the app. The app has an extern lib (zxing) to scan QR-codes for easy login functions. And my problems there were how to get the archiving file from the generic xcode archive to a genuine ios app archive. I succeeded by following this guide (http://pulkitsinghal.blogspot.nl/2012/03/wrong-archive-ios-app-archive-vs.html).
Which involved changing the 'Skip Install' setting to YES in the Target>Build Settings of my Zxing lib.

All done and well. Except, now I ran my app on my simulator and I couldn't connect to the server anymore. The hostname appeared to be (null), which was described in my Settings.Bundle.

I haven't touched the programming which created that settings item. So how could it have been disappearing on me?

Could it be that by changing the bundle identifier of the build settings in my mainproject and the zxing lib? Could it be something else?

Any thoughts on how my previous changes might have impacted the disappearance of the Settings.bundle?

(I could provide code of any kind ofc. but atm I wouldn't know what to post)

A possible solution could be reverting things back to an earlier revision of course, but I don't know what made it disappear in the first place. Or what could make it disappear. And wouldn't want to lose a few day's worth of work.